# How to create a custom design product attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute

I want to create a product attribute like below image. When user click add then it will add two new textboxes. if clicked on delete button it will get deleted. All the data will be stored serialized and stored. when open it will deserialized the data.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpVel.jpg]

Comment: @teja can you help me on this?